# PXE: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed

Tags: linux, pxe

I am trying to PXE boot Debian 11, but run into a very strange problem; strange because until earlier today it worked fine. Then I made a small change (installed nfs-common and made a change in /etc/fstab to mount a remote NFS share).

Now the grub menu shows up - this is the menu entry:

```
menuentry 'Debian 11' {
  set background_color=black
  linux /debian11/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-27-amd64 console=tty0 console=ttyS0 ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs ro nfsroot=192.168.50.111:/image/debian11,vers=3,nolock panic=60 ipv6.disable=1 rootwait ignore_loglevel
  initrd /debian11/boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-27-amd64
}
```

The kernel boots, but in the middle of it all, it panics:

```
[    4.386889] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    4.410676] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/nfs-bottom ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
done.
mount: mounting /run on /root/run failed: No such file or directory
run-init: can't change directory to '/root': Stale file handle
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
run-init: can't change directory to '/root': Stale file handle
run-init: can't change directory to '/root': Stale file handle
run-init: can't change directory to '/root': Stale file handle
run-init: can't change directory to '/root': Stale file handle
run-init: can't change directory to '/root': Stale file handle
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
Rebooting automatically due to panic= boot argument
```

This grub config has worked fine, and any way, the init-bottom script would be called before the kernel starts, yes? So why does it die so late?